# How can I remove the word "Said..." from blog comments?

Tags: comments, customization, blogger

How can I remove the word "Said..." that appears after the visitor name in blog post comments?

This is the markup I have:

```
<div id='Blog1_comments-block-wrapper'> 
<dl class='avatar-comment-indent' id='comments-block'> 
<dt class='comment-author blog-author' id='c3919237356098092138'> 
<a name='c3919237356098092138'></a> 
<div class="avatar-image-container vcard"><span dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.blogger.com/profile/16491601201868141572" rel="nofollow" onclick="" class="avatar-hovercard" id="av-0-16491601201868141572"><img src="http://img1.blogblog.com/img/blank.gif" width="35" height="35" alt="" class="delayLoad" style="display: none;" longdesc="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-1os8iMuN1wE/TklKwE48-gI/AAAAAAAAAEs/5sOQZ04rtSc/s45/buddy%25252Bicon.png" title="Kariem Zaki"> 

 <noscript><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-1os8iMuN1wE/TklKwE48-gI/AAAAAAAAAEs/5sOQZ04rtSc/s45/buddy%25252Bicon.png" width="35" height="35" class="photo" alt=""></noscript></a></span></div> 
 <a href='http://www.blogger.com/profile/16491601201868141572' rel='nofollow'>Kariem Zaki</a> 
 said...
  </dt> 
  <dd class='comment-body' id='Blog1_cmt-3919237356098092138'> 
  <p> 
  thank you for this great post
  </p> 
  </dd> 
  <dd class='comment-footer'> 
  <span class='comment-timestamp'> 
  <a href='http://kzsubs.blogspot.com/2011/08/source-code.html?showComment=1316195035535#c3919237356098092138' title='comment permalink'> 
  September 16, 2011 7:43 PM
  </a> 
  <span class='item-control blog-admin pid-738993793'> 
  <a class='comment-delete' href='http://www.blogger.com/delete-comment.g?blogID=5161183995769593091&postID=3919237356098092138' title='Delete Comment'> 
  <img src='//www.blogger.com/img/icon_delete13.gif'/> 
  </a> 
  </span> 
  </span> 
  </dd> 
  </dl> 
  </div>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is edit the **template** of your blog, see http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?answer=46870